# Datatables is stucking on Processing with same name of columns on both sides

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, datatables

I don't know how to google this issue on internet because I don't know how to explaining shortly.

Pictures are better than thousand words!

This image is showing how is my table currently. Actually is showing data but is stucking on "Processing", so paginate is not working, neither "search"... nothing.
[image]

Next image show what I need to do with data if I want to make datatables working as normally... I have to avoid one of the columns on datatables.
[image]

But, if I comment or delete a column into the table on the view. I get the same issue!
[image]

Can anyone help me on this issue? I cannot find how to fix it!

Comment: "*Pictures are better than thousand words!*", No, it is almost the worst thing you can do on a site where programming problems is discussed. Why should an image of some code be better than posting the same code as readable text?

Comment: Because is esear to explain in this way... Besides, my problem seems is not with my code, because it is working fine if I leave a blank column in the table into the view. The problem should be another thing. That's the reason I share image instead the code. I cannot find the proper way to explian the issue and try to find anyone who has the same problem or similar.

Comment: Well, good luck :) Personally I cannot decrypt such images. I have the feeling you experience a very common  erroneous way of using DataTables, like your serverside script does not fulfill the requirements for being used along with `serverSide: true`, the fact that it hangs on "processing" without (apparently) raising errors strongly indicate that - but how should I know for sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't notice at all about 'colspan="2"'. Datatables needs to get the same quantity of columns on both sides.